# how to compare variable in different columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare three variable in three dataframe columns. but it gave me an error **TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'**. below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Entry','Middle','Exit'])
entry_value = '17.98'
middle_value = '12.16'
exit_value = '1.2'
df = df.append({'Entry' : entry_value , 'Middle' : middle_value, 'Exit' : exit_value}, ignore_index = True)
entry_value = '19.98'
middle_value = '192.16'
exit_value = '1.1'
if entry_value in {df['Entry'] , df['Middle'] , df['Exit']} :
    print('entry')
elif middle_value in {df['Entry'] , df['Middle'] , df['Exit']} :
    print('middle')
elif exit_value in {df['Entry'] , df['Middle'] , df['Exit']} :
    print('exit')
else:
    print('wawo')`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for a column but if you want to search for multiple columns you must either convert them to a single list or define them as a single series.

```
if entry_value in df[['Entry','Middle','Exit']].stack().to_list():
    print('entry')
elif middle_value in df[['Entry','Middle','Exit']].stack().to_list():
    print('middle')
elif exit_value in df[['Entry','Middle','Exit']].stack().to_list():
    print('exit')
else:
    print('wawo')
```

If you are searching all columns, you do not need to define individual column names:

```
#dont use
#df[['Entry','Middle','Exit']].stack()

#use
#df.stack()
if entry_value in df.stack().to_list():
    print('entry')
elif middle_value in df.stack().to_list():
    print('middle')
elif exit_value in df.stack().to_list():
    print('exit')
else:
    print('wawo')
```

Comment: i tried `entry_value = '17.98'` which is already in list as define above but it didn't work. it came to else directly. it was suppose to print `entry`

Comment: can you check it again ? i edited.

Comment: also i have more columns. not just these three

Comment: if there are many columns it will be easier to use `df.stack().to_list()`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [`pandas.DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check if any of the columns selected contain a certain value.

Try this :

```
cols= ['Entry', 'Middle', 'Exit']

if any(df[cols].isin([entry_value])):
    print('entry')
elif any(df[cols].isin([middle_value])):
    print('middle')
elif any(df[cols].isin([exit_value])):
    print('exit')
else:
    print('wawo')
```

NB: Not sure why you're assigning different values to the same variables when constructing your datarame but you should know that [`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is deprecated.

> FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be
> removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.